# iterating returned JSON OBJECT using jQUERY $.each()

Tags: jquery, json, iteration

I'm using jQuery's $.ajax method to call getjson.php which returns a JSON object using PHPs json_encode($data). The Structure of my JSON looks like this...

> [
>       {
>           "StoreKey": "84",
>           "StoreName": "Region1",
>           "0": "4,055.37",
>           "1": "2,668.29",
>           "2": "4,454.81",
>           "3": "4,789.99",
>           "4": "none",
>           "5": "none",
>           "6": "none",
>           "7": "15,968.46"
>       },
>       {
>           "StoreKey": "26",
>           "StoreName": "Region2",
>           "0": "2,368.09",
>           "1": "2,270.24",
>           "2": "1,806.76",
>           "3": "1,656.15",
>           "4": "none",
>           "5": "none",
>           "6": "none",
>           "7": "8,101.24"
>       },
>       {
>           "StoreKey": "Daily",
>           "StoreName": "Totals",
>           "0": "92,614.45",
>           "1": "98,126.78",
>           "2": "104,157.04",
>           "3": "102,581.87",
>           "4": "none",
>           "5": "none",
>           "6": "none",
>           "7": 397480.14
>       } ]

I can display the JSON object using $('#responseDiv').html(result); });
but I would like to parse through through each row using the $.each() method.

When iterating through the JSON object using $.each() only the last JSON object is displayed. This displays the last JSON object -> "7": 397480.14.

```
var data = $.parseJSON(result);
  $.each(data,function(row,store)  {    
   $.each(store,function(key,value) {
     $('#responseDiv').html(value); 
     });        
  })
```

The goal is to wrap the JSON objects in < tr > tags for each row and < td > tags for each column for a table/grid look.**

AJAX Request Function.

```
$.ajax  //jQuery Syntax-ajax.api!
  ({
     type: "POST",
     url: "includes/getjson.php", //----my php scripts/codes
     data: "date="+x, 
     datatype: "json",
     success: function(result)
     {
      var data = $.parseJSON(result);
      $.each(data,function(row,store)  {    
        $.each(store,function(key,value) {
            $('#responseDiv').html(value);  });     
           }) 
     }
   }); 
}
```

It's something I'm not doing or doing incorrectly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the content of #responseDiv each time - you want to append it

```
$('#responseDiv').html($('#responseDiv').html() + value);
```

or, shorter:

```
$('#responseDiv').append(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create a table with rows based no the json object, i would recommend using a templating engine like [jTemplate](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/) or [Jquery Template](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/). Then you would simply create a template of your  and send your return object to it to render.

```
<!-- Template content --> 
<textarea id="myTemplate" style="display:none"> 

        {#foreach $T as record}
        <tr>
           <td>{$T.record.StoreKey}</td>
           <td>{$T.record.StoreName}</td>
                       <td>{$T.record.0}</td>
        </tr>
        {#/for}
</textarea>
```

Your HTML would be

```
<table>
    <tbody id="placeholder">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

then you would simply send your json result to the templating engine.

```
$.ajax  //jQuery Syntax-ajax.api!
  ({
     type: "POST",
     url: "includes/getjson.php", //----my php scripts/codes
     data: "date="+x, 
     datatype: "json",
     success: function(result)
     {
    $("#placeholder").setTemplateElement("myTemplate").processTemplate(result);
     }
   }); 
}
```